# Windows 7 entry missing from grub after 12.04 installation

Tags: grub2, partitioning, dual-boot

I've read several answers to related questions here, but have not found one that matches my situation.

I assisted a colleague to reinstall Windows 7 from a recovery partition. We then booted into Windows, shrank the Windows partition (/dev/sda3) and the installed Ubuntu 12.04 (we partitioned the remaining space into / (sda5), /home (sda6), /swap (sda7) and free space for another Windows drive later.) I specified GRUB to install to /dev/sda. /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2 were recovery/system partitions.

After rebooting, grub showed the Ubuntu boot options in the menu, and an option for a Windows recovery on /dev/sda1 and a similar one for /dev/sda2. It did not show an entry for Windows 7 on /dev/sda3. I booted into Ubuntu and ran `sudo update-grub`, but this failed to detect Windows on /dev/sda3. I checked the contents of /dev/sda3 and Windows is still there.

I hope I can resolve this soon, as this is not a good first impression of an LTS release to someone who has just decided to start using Ubuntu/GNU/Linux!

Comment: My guess is that one of the Recovery options will actually boot the normal Windows installation. Also note that Windows 7 installations have *2* partitions, one containing just the bootloader (the System partition) and the main partition containing the rest. Grub needs to chainload the System partition, which is probably *not* /dev/sda3. Please try both of the recovery options (being careful not to accidentally run any recovery operations) and also run boot info script http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/ and post the RESULTS.txt which it produces.

Comment: @Jordan Uggla: Thanks! :) Yes, the "Windows Loader" on /dev/sda2 loaded Windows 7. I wish I could "Accept" your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that one of the two entries in the existing menu was actually an entry for Windows 7, so the solution was to try both of the entries (while being careful not to accidentally start any actual Windows recovery operations). I'm writing this as an answer so that it can be accepted, but I'd also recommend filing a bug report about the mislabeled Windows entry by running `ubuntu-bug os-prober`.